# How to reload a view in laravel after insert with JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm inserting records into a table using jQuery ajax. It works fine and returns a flash message that notifies that the record was inserted successfully. Now my problem is after the record have been inserted I don't know how to reload my table so that changes can be reflected.

**Note** I'm inserting via a bootstrap modal on the same page the table lies.

This is the controller that returns my records:

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $subjects = Subject::all();


    return view('subjects.show', compact('subjects'));
}
```

After records are return this is how I'm displaying it:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Level</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($subjects as $subject)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$subject->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$subject->level}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" href="#" role="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit text-info"></i></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" href="#" role="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger"></i></a>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

This is my script to insert record:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#subject-form', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            /* Act on the event */

            var name = $('#name').val();
            var level = $('#level').val();

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $("#subject-form").attr('action'),
                data: {name: name, level: level},
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);

                    if (response.success) {
                        $.notify({
                            icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check',
                            message: response.success
                          },{
                              type: 'info',
                              timer: 4000,
                              offset: 20,
                              spacing: 10,
                              z_index: 1031,
                              delay: 5000,
                              placement: {
                                from: "bottom",
                                align: "right"
                              },

                              animate: {
                                enter: 'animated fadeInDown',
                                exit: 'animated fadeOutUp'
                              },
                        });
                    } else {
                        // display error
                    }

                    $('#subject-modal').modal('toggle');
                }
            });
```

This is the controller method that inserts the record and generate a flash response:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //

   //return json_encode(request('name'));
    $response = array();

   if (Subject::create(request(['name', 'level']))) {

       $response['success'] = '<b>'.request('name').'</b>'.' created successfully';
   } else {
       $response['fail'] ='Error creating subject: <b>'.request('name').'</b>'.'. Try again, if problem persist contact administrator';
   }

    return \Response::json($response);


}
```

Are there ways I can make this work? Appreciate feed backs and suggestions. Thanks!!!

Comment: Why not just calling window.location.reload() in JavaScript? Otherwise you need to refresh the HTML content in the browser. Ajax is capable of delivering that content as well.

Comment: @btl window.location.reload() reloads the page but doesn't work will closing my dialog and displaying my flash message. How do I refresh the html content?

Comment: Make an AJAX request and return the new data  with return response()->json($reponse);. Then in the success callback append the data to your HTML document.

Comment: @btl in my controller store method, I'm sure that's where it should be done, but now base on what I have I can I return both the response and the flash message?

Comment: @btl I'm currently returning only the flash mess with a field from the response.

Comment: Set Subject::create(request(['name', 'level'])) to a variable and return it in your response. $model = Subject::create(request(['name', 'level'])... then return \Response::json(['response' => $response, 'model' => $model]);

Comment: One more thing with this, I'll be appending the model to the table and displaying the response as a flash message right? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: I would add to the table first and then display the message once you know it's been successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions for this.

1. `window.location.reload()` to reload the page.
2. Send the newly added record as a response and in success call back append this to your current table showing all records. (no reload will be required)

**EDIT**

Your controller method might look like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //

   //return json_encode(request('name'));
    $response = array();

   if ($subject = Subject::create(request(['name', 'level']))) {

       $response['success'] = '<b>'.request('name').'</b>'.' created successfully';
       $response['subject'] = $subject;
   } else {
       $response['fail'] ='Error creating subject: <b>'.request('name').'</b>'.'. Try again, if problem persist contact administrator';
   }

    return \Response::json($response);


}
```

Now your response array has an object (newly created subject record) and you can access it via `subject` key within your success callback.

Give your table an `id` and access it using jquery to append a `<tr> </tr>` element containing your `subject` record..

Comment: How do I do option 2?

Comment: @NathanSiafa, check If the edit is enough for you to understand the idea.

Comment: I did this `$('#subjects').append('<td>'+response.subject+'</td>')` and I got `[object Object]`

Comment: for me to archieve that I had to the id to the tbody tag.

Comment: @Nathan Siafa Glad you finished the job :)

Answer (score 2):

Get response from controller and append new row into the table.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#subject-form").attr('action'),
            data: {name: name, level: level},
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);

                if (response.success) {
                    var html = '<tr>';
                    html = '        <td>' + response.subject.name + '</td>';
                    html = '<td>' + response.subject.level + '</td>';
                    html = '<td>';
                    html = '<a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" href="#" role="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit text-info"></i></a>';
                    html = '</td>';
                    html = '<td>';
                    html = '<a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" href="#" role="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash text-danger"></i></a>';
                    html = '</td>';
                    html = '</tr>';
                    $("table.table-responsive").append(html);
                    });
                } else {
                    // display error
                }

                $('#subject-modal').modal('toggle');
            }
        });
```

`Controller` Code

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $response = array();
    $data["name"] = request('name');
    $data["level"] = request('level');
    $subject = Subject::create($data);
    if ($subject) {
        $response['success'] = '<b>' . request('name') . '</b>' . ' created successfully';
        $response['subject'] = $subject;
    } else {
        $response['fail'] = 'Error creating subject: <b>' . request('name') . '</b>' . '. Try again, if problem persist contact administrator';
    }

    return \Response::json($response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use load function. Give your table an id and use this whenever you want:

```
var url = '/page_adress';
$('#table_id').load(url + '#table_id>*');
```